# Order by DATE does not properly list the dates selected from DB

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

I have a simple query that goes like this...

```
SELECT Distinct(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ListDate, 1)) as ListDate 
FROM tblData
```

The dates gets pulled up like this...

```
01/13/17
04/06/17
10/12/16
07/28/16
05/24/16
07/10/17
```

Now, it doesn't matter if I do either one of these..

```
Order By ListDate ASC or Order By ListDate DESC
```

The dates are not in order, they are all mixed up 17's with 16's

I tried to do

```
Order By Cast(listDate as date)
```

But it gives me error stating that

> Order By items must appear in the select list if Select Distinct is
>   Specified?

Any way I can order the dates in ascending order

Comment: `DATE` <> `STRING`

Comment: Alias the column with a different name than listDate.  Order by is using the text value of ListDate aliased in the select.  But you want it ordered by the date datatype Listdate from the table.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific SQL there...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method you can use is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ListDate, 1) as ListDate 
FROM tblData
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ListDate, 1)
ORDER BY MIN(ListDate) DESC;
```

In other words, if you use `GROUP BY`, you have more flexibility over the query.